# How to create a shared folder on Xbox One S?

Tags: xbox-one

Using the File Explorer app on ***Xbox One S***.
I'm looking for a way to create a folder and share it (and it's contents) with other profiles on the Xbox.

***My Scenario:***
I have an Xbox One S with 2 users.
User #1 creates a folder using File Explorer and adds some files to that folder (text files, images, etc).
User #1 logs off, User #2 logs in, starts the File Explorer app. Folder created by User #1 is not visible to User #2.
How can User #1 create a "public" or "shared" folder?

Comment: I've never tried that on the internal Xbox HD, but external drives seem to work for separate profiles, is a USB drive an option for you? Also, i dont use OneDrive personally, but folder sharing may be possible (it is with Dropbox but theres no XBL app for that AFAIK).

Comment: @Dpeif - I haven't tried a USB drive. I was hoping to use the internal HHD.. didn't want to use cloud storage either (OneDrive, etc.).

Comment: gotcha. i only have access to 1 profile so i cant test. It sounds like a security/permissions restriction, but I cant tell if its XBL determining permissions, or just the app enforcing it There doesnt appear to be any contextual options in the File Explorer app for sharing, and my only other idea was to use a free app like VLC to see if you could circumvent the file explorer app and both view the folder (but sadly VLC only registers network and external drives, not the internal HD). Will continue to look into it though.